# Get from one number an array of numbers without brackets

Tags: javascript

Need to receive:

digitize(12345) -> [5,4,3,2,1]

I wrote a code:

```
function digitize(n) {
let arr = Array.from(n + '');
return arr.reverse();
}

console.log(digitize(12345));
```

Output: [ '5', '4', '3', '2', '1' ]

This is very close, but this is showing an array of strings. How can I get an array of numbers (without the quotes), instead?

Comment: @trincot Yeah, I was tripping over that, too. I edited OP's question to clarify this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could map (the second parameter of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) with `Number`.

This approach works only for positive integers which are equal or less than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (`9007199254740991`).

```js
function digitize(n) {
    return Array
        .from(n.toString(), Number)
        .reverse();
}

console.log(digitize(12345));
```

Comment: This is wrong. It won't work for `digitize(1e21)` and larger numbers as those will be formatted in scientific notation `1e21` by to string (granted, other solutions therefore have flaws related to float precision).

Comment: @LMD, of course this works only for positive integers which are equal or less than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: @LMD, if you need larger values, you could take [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead.

Comment: function digitize(n) {
 const str = n.toString();
 const myArr = str.split("");
 const reversedArr = myArr.map(function (x) { 
  return parseInt(x, 10); 
}).sort((a,b)=>{return b-a});
 return reversedArr
}

console.log(digitize(12345))

Comment: Indeed, sometimes we learn by getting an appropriate advice. I'll be obliged if you point out the exact mistake for what my answer has been down voted. In my opinion, I have answered with the right code for the person who has asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider a recursive function, and do it without conversion to string:

```js
function digitize(n) {
    return n < 10 ? [n] : [n % 10, ...digitize(Math.floor(n / 10))];
}

console.log(digitize(12345));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not go the "hacky", buggy and presumably less efficient route over stringification here:

```js
function digitize(n) {
    const digits = [];
    while (n >= 1) {
        digits.push(n % 10);
        n = Math.floor(n / 10);
    }
    return digits;
}
```

or using a `do-while` depending if you want `digitize(0)` to be `[0]` instead of `[]`:

```js
function digitize(n) {
    const digits = [];
    do {
        digits.push(n % 10);
        n = Math.floor(n / 10);
    } while (n >= 1)
    return digits;
}
```

this will still fail for some large floats due to precision issues though.

Answer (score -1):

Try

// The following function would give you an array of numbers in descending order of the digits of a number given as an argument to the function

```
function digitize(n) {
 const str = n.toString();
 const myArr = str.split("");
 const reversedArr = myArr.map(function (x) { 
  return parseInt(x, 10); 
}).sort((a,b)=>{return b-a});
 return reversedArr
}

console.log(digitize(12345))
console.log(digitize(45343))
console.log(digitize(484643))

// [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
// [5, 4, 4, 3, 3]
// [8, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3]
```

// The following function would give you an array of numbers in reversed order of the digits of a number given as an argument to the function

```
function digitize(n) {
 const str = n.toString();
 const myArr = str.split("");
 const reversedArr = myArr.map(function (x) { 
  return parseInt(x, 10); 
}).reverse();
 return reversedArr
}

console.log(digitize(12345));
console.log(digitize(45343));
console.log(digitize(484643));

// [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
// [3, 4, 3, 5, 4]
// [3, 4, 6, 4, 8, 4]
```